# React Router DOM listen for Route changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My react app is inside a java struts project, which includes a header. There is a certain element in that header that changes depending on certain routes being hit.

For this it would be much simpler to listen to when a route changes where my Routes are defined. As opposed to doing it in every route.

Here is my

### App.js

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  useHistory,
  useLocation,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Page 1 </Link>
      <Link to="/2">Page 2 </Link>
      <Link to="/3">Page 3 </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const h = useHistory();
  const l = useLocation();

  const { listen } = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("location change");
  }, [l]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("history change");
  }, [h]);

  h.listen(() => {
    console.log("history listen");
  });

  listen((location) => {
    console.log("listen change");
  });

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path={"/"} component={Nav} />
      <Route path={"/"} component={PageOne} exact />
      <Route path={"/2"} component={PageTwo} exact />
      <Route path={"/3"} component={PageThree} exact />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

None of the console logs get hit when clicking on the links in the Nav component. Is there a way around this?

I have a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-wildflower-d9f5k?file=/src/App.js:326-489) to test this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `react-router-dom` passes the navigation object down the React tree.

You're trying to access history and location in your App component, but there's nothing "above" your App component to provide it a history or location.

If you instead put your `useLocation` and `useHistory` inside of PageOne/PageTwo/PageThree components, it works as intended.

Updated your codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-lamarr-bzspg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do that, and that's the recommended practice. It's just that in my actual project I have 50 different routes. I'd rather do it once, not 50 times, if you get me?

Comment: You could make a ref to the Router (iirc where the route state is stored) and just read state from App.tsx